# Invalid conversion from void* to int*

Tags: c++, fork, shared-memory, mmap

I have a global variable:

```
static int *avgg;
```

In main function:

```
avgg = mmap(NULL, sizeof *avgg, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

pid_t  pid, wpid;
int status;

 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) {
      avg(argc,argv);
      print_avg();

  }
 else{ 
     while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0) {

     }
 cout<<"Parent process";
     print_avg();
```

By using mmap Im trying to share memory between parent and child process but Im getting error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
                 MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to implicitly convert the return value of `mmap`, which is a `void *`, into an `int *`, and your compiler settings don't allow you to do that without an explicit cast.

Try `avgg = (int *)mmap(NULL, sizeof *avgg, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`

Comment: _"You're casting"_ No, he's not.

Comment: Good catch, meant converting.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that `mmap` returns `void*`, not `int*`.

You may convert the former to the latter *if you are sure that your data are compatible*, but you'll need a cast to do so because no matching *implicit* conversion exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can fix this problem with this code segment :

```
 int file_descriptor = shm_open("/test_shared_memory", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
 void *address = mmap ( NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, file_descriptor, 0);
 // For checking that the address mapped correctly or not.
 if (address == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf("Memory map failed. :(");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: To solve your problem you most just convert you int* into void*.